# Invalid Scopes: user_about_me, user_website. This message is only shown to developers

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I use Facebook login in my webapp. I am getting this error.

"Invalid Scopes: user_about_me, user_website. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

How to fix this? Do I need to change anything in my Facebook App page?

Thanks

Comment: Both of those are not listed as valid permissions any more, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference#u

Comment: @CBroe So how can I fix it?

Comment: By removing those permissions from the list that you are asking for ...?